# Webpack banner plugin work with file from another plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there is a way to make webpack-banner-plugin can work to file from another plugin like copy-webpack-plugin that copy js/css file?, It's only process file from entry point, I'm trying set entryOnly to false but still not process another file beside from entry point.

Comment: Could you show us some code on what you have already done/tried?

Comment: @FMK Check my [webpack](https://jsfiddle.net/ur8zg6Le/) config.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with my config, but **entryOnly** option on banner i thought for let the banner plugin read all file that compile on webpack not only from entry point but when i set false is still process only from entry point.